# Does ko.dataFor() work with `select` elements?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to use `ko.dataFor()` on a `select` element but it's returning the whole ViewModel. I'm expecting to get the object of the selected `option`, but I always get the ViewModel instead. I've tried passing the `select` and the `option` but either way I get the same result.

http://jsfiddle.net/LzAAB/3/

```
<select id="companies" data-bind="options: companies, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: ' ' "></select>
<br/>
ko.DataFor(select)<br/>
<textarea id="a" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
ko.DataFor(option)<br/>
<textarea id="b" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
<br/>
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div>


function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.companies = ko.observableArray([{id:1, name: "Chevy"},{id:2, name: "Ford"}, {id:2, name: "Dodge"}]);
    self.countries = ko.observableArray([{id:1, name: "USA"},{id:2, name: "Canada"}, {id:2, name: "Mexico"}]);
}

var vm = new MyViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

$("#companies").change(function(){    
    $("#a").val("dataFor("+this.id+"):"+  ko.toJSON(ko.dataFor(this)));

    var selectedOption = $(this).find(":selected")[0];
    $("#b").val("dataFor("+this.id+"):"+  ko.toJSON(ko.dataFor(selectedOption)));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the `ko.dataFor()` function gives you is the object for which an element is binding to.  It's the same object your bindings would see if you accessed the `$data` context variable.  The option elements generated by the `options` binding uses the same context so you won't see any difference there.  It's only relevant to bindings where the binding context is changed (e.g., in a foreach binding).

---

It would be better if you used knockout's features to access the objects you want instead of relying on jquery.  Create an observable and bind the value to the select.  Then you can do what you want with the selected value.

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();
    self.companies = ko.observableArray(...);
    self.countries = ko.observableArray(...);
}
```

```
<select id="companies"
        data-bind="value: selectedCompany,
                   options: companies,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsCaption: ' '">
</select>
<br/>
Selected<br/>
<textarea cols="40" rows="10" data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedCompany)">
</textarea>
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/z9ckd/)